# "Let's wait and see"

Tags: idiom

Is there a Latin idiom for deciding to sit back and wait instead of acting immediately?
If I want to let things evolve for a little more before taking any action, I could use the phrase "let's wait and see" in English.
Unfortunately I couldn't find an attested or idiomatic way of expressing this in Latin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verb *ex(s)pecto* covers this concept.

Plautus, *Poenulus* 12:

> exsurge, praeco, fac populo audientiam;
>   **iam dudum exspecto, si tuom officium scias**:
>   exerce vocem, quam per vivisque et † colis.
>
> '...For a long time now, I've been waiting to see if you know your duty'

Terence, *Andria* 34:

> SIMO. nil istac opus est arte ad hanc rem quam paro,
>   sed eis quas semper in te intellexi sitas,
>   fide et taciturnitate. SOSIA. **exspecto quid velis.**
>
> 'I'm waiting to see what you want.'

Cicero, *In Verrem* 2.2.127:

> cum suffragiis tres ex tribus generibus creati sunt, res revocatur ad sortem. perfecerat iste imperio ut pro suffragio Theomnastus, familiaris suus, in tribus illis renuntiaretur: in sorte, cui imperare non potuerat, **exspectabant homines quidnam acturus esset.**
>
> '...all men were waiting to see what he intended to do.'